# QGIS Summing attributes of polygons contained inside region polygons. Some share boundaries. Intersection gets unwanted neighbors

Tags: qgis, polygon, summarizing

[image: Simplified View]So I am trying to sum up populations from a census polygons layer into a region polygon layer. Now I want to sum up the total population contained in each region polygon (A & B).
Here's the problem:  I can't figure out the right spatial relationship to use in "Join Attribute by location (summary)". The "Intersection" selection pulls in polys from the neighboring regions (they often share a segment with the outside boundary of the region). In the image, poly 15 would also get summed into region B totals, and poly 15 gets added in B. Using "Contains" & "Within" fail because it won't get the internal polygons who share a boundary with their covering region poly, and "Overlap" seems strangely random in what it includes.
Since the shared boundary edges were created from the region polygons I am confident their geometries is aligned (no tiny gaps).
Suggestions?

Comment: Run an overlay (intersection or union) and recalculate your area fields.  The overlay will split the polygons where they cross regions.  Then you can process the results further in a pivot table.  You might also look at the Overlay Analysis tool.

Comment: Thanks!  The population polys have already been intersected against the region polys - that's why they have such neatly cropped borders. I can union them against the region polys, but don't know how to sum the attributes during such an operation. Not sure how to do a join, but I'll do more homework.  If it wasn't obvious, I'm very new to QGIS. :-)

Comment: Still having trouble with this. I've used an overlay to split the population polys so they don't cross regions, but I still can't seem to sum the resulting polys that overlap with each region, since their all spatial matching seem to also select all adjacent touching polys in neighboring regions. I thought "overlap" meant they had to share some area and not just a boundary?

Comment: How are you going to sum the population?  I was thinking you would get relative proportions by area for each census in a region and use the same proportions applied to the populations in a census poly.  If so once the overlay was done and areas recalculated then some work in a pivot table would get your the populations in each region.  That work could be joined back to your regions by a simple table join using the region number.  You might look at the Overlap Analysis tool as an alternative to the intersect/pivot table approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with intersecting polygons, an alternative approach would be to convert the population polygons to points.

By using **Pole of inaccessibility**, you can convert the population polygons to points with confidence that the point is **inside** the population polygon (and hence inside your region polygon).

Then use **Join Attribute by location (summary)** with the point layer as the join layer and your region layer as the base layer.

Comment: Ohhh I hadn't thought about converting the population polys to points. That's kinda brilliant. Thank you. I'll post if this solves my problem. I'd still love to know what spatial relationship operation effectively selects polygons inside my region polys where they are either contained OR share a boundary.  Strangely overlap doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Remember you can vote up the answer ("this answer is useful") without necessarily marking it as the accepted answer.